# Tensorflow-text import problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"  # or "tensorflow" or "torch"

import keras_nlp
import keras_core as keras
import time
preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor.from_preset(
    "gpt2_base_en",
    sequence_length=128,
)
gpt2_lm = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLM.from_preset(
    "gpt2_base_en", preprocessor=preprocessor
)

start = time.time()

output = gpt2_lm.generate("How are you", max_length=200)
print("\nGPT-2 output:")
print(output)

end = time.time()
print(f"TOTAL TIME ELAPSED: {end - start:.2f}s")
```

This is the error
`ImportError: GPT2Tokenizer requires the tensorflow-textpackage. Please install withpip install tensorflow-text.`

Here are my versions
`Python: 3.9.17 Tensorflow: 2.10.1 tensorflow text: 2.10.0 keras-nlp:  0.6.1` 
Im using anaconda, but all my libraries are installed with pip. Ive tried a fresh env and fresh installs of all relevant libraries.